# Doctrine 2 - Getting number of rows from entity

Tags: doctrine-orm

I am trying to get the number of rows of a table from a Doctrine2 Entity.

For example, let's assume I have a table 'Car' with 4 records. I would like to implement a static (or not) method 'getNbCars()' which would return '4'.

```
use \MyVendor\MyModule\Entity\Car   

$car = new Car();
$car->getNbCars(); // would return 4
// or
Car::getNbCars(); // same
```

I looked into the documentation and the NativeNamedQueries annotation but I don't seem to be able to get through.

Does someone know how I can do that or if I am completely out and shouldn't do that from the entity itself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine2 entities are POPOs (plain-old-php-objects) so having a method of this type (i.e: 'table' operations) on an instance of Car doesn't really make sense. This is what `EntityRepository` is for - you can define a repository for your `Car` entity and group `Car` related queries therein:

Usage looks something like the following:

```
$nbCars = $em->getRepository('MyVendor\MyModule\Entity\Car')->getNbCars();
```

You would then define a method `CarRepository::getNbCars()` using either DQL, SQL or the queryBuilder (your preference) to define the query to count your cars - presumably something like `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM car;` if you were using raw SQL.

I like this approach because you can group (and reuse) queries based on entities pretty easily this way.

You'll find some useful info in the docs about creating a custom repo here:

- [Symfony2 docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes)
- [Doctrine2 docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html#custom-repositories)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Darragh, it is indeed the correct way to do that. The issue is in the fact that my coworker is using a generic way through configuration files, and the only way it could have worked for him would have been to use Car->getNbCars();